# Encontrar combinaciónes de un arreglo sin repeticiones con cierta longitud

Tags: javascript, concat, reduce

Estoy buscando una alternativa que me devuelva las diferentes combinaciones que pueda tener un arreglo.

Donde hago un filtrado para conseguir solo los de cierta longitud.

*Cuento con la siguiente función:*

```
const alphabet = "abcdefg".split("");
function obtenerConjuntoPotencia(datos) {
  return datos.reduce((a, v) => a.concat(a.map(d => [v].concat(d))), [[]]);
}
obtenerConjuntoPotencia(alphabet).filter(item => item.length === 5).length
```

*Resultado*

```
21
```

El problema es al usar un arreglo grande como **200** en lugar a uno de 7, me quedo sin recursos, nunca termina la función y necesito que pueda correr en cualquier navegador.

**Muchas gracias por su ayuda!**

Comment: ¿Tienes idea de matemáticamente cuantas combinaciones quieres almacenar? ¿Has hecho las matemáticas para eso?  ¡Es una locura total! Vamos a ponerle números. No voy a entrar en detalles, pero la cantidad de combinaciones (elementos en tu array) siempre será igual a 2^n. En este caso para 10 elementos, 2^10 = 1024, lo cual es una cantidad calculable. Ahora imagínate 2^200 = 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376. ¡¡¡No sé de donde vas a sacar tanta memoria!!!

Comment: Si solo quieres calcular las combinaciones con una longitud fija, digamos, como el ejemplo que adjuntas la fórmula es nCm = 10C5= 252 (obviamente en tu salida omitiste números porque acabo de ejecutar tu programa y me da 252). Ahora vamos a darle 200C5 = 2,535,650,040 ¡Sigue siendo una locura! Sea lo que sea que quieras, créeme, no creo estés seleccionando la vía correcta para hacerlo. Explica tu problema a ver si alguien te ofrece una alternativa, porque esa vía definitivamente no camina.

Comment: Hola, te agradezco mucho tus respuestas, pensé que esa podía ser la mejor manera, pero a como lo dices no hay memoria que me alcance para resolverlo de esa forma. La intención es hacer varios juegos de lotería con diferentes bases de datos que me proporcionan las imágenes.

Comment: Pero para ello,, simplemente almacena los números que te compren o algo así. Siempre puedes validar que una combinación sea válida sin tener que generar todas las combinaciones posibles. También puedes validar que no haya sido escogida antes, porque los que hayan sido escogidos los guardas. Y a la hora de escoger un ganador, bien puedes generar una combinación aleatoria con random. Ninguna de esas cosas requiere generar todas las combinaciones. Siempre puedes saber, como mismo yo lo calculé, cuantas combinaciones posibles hay.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez más a detalle la idea es con esas bases de datos, digamos Pokemon, me da todos los personajes, con una función inicial que me los devuelve uno por uno al azar. Ya con eso quiero darle digamos a 30 jugadores plantillas de 16 imágenes, para que yo al ir mostrando Pokémon por Pokémon ellos puedan ir tachando en su plantilla los que van saliendo.

Comment: Pero puedes facilmente generar de entre 800 pokemones,  30 platillas diferentes de 16 imágenes cada una sin calcular todas las combinaciones posibles. Usa random para ello guardando las plantillas en un array y asegurándote de que cada plantilla que generes no haya sido generada antes. Puedes editar tu pregunta y centrarla a ese problema, que sí puede resolverse sin gastar tanta memoria.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Creo que tienes razón, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Ahora no tengo tiempo para una respuesta tan elaborada, pero checa esté [fragmento de código](https://gist.github.com/JaimeMenendez/8ab9466b5e1be3b4dc482d190ce2b164). Un poco feo pero funciona. Si sólo quieres calcular el número de combinaciones por ejemplo, de 6 en 5 o de 200 en 10 usa `calcularCombinaciones(6, 5)` o `calcularCombinaciones(200,10)`. Si quieres obtener 15 combinaciones de cierto arreglo, cada una de longitud 5, usa algo cómo `obtenerCombinaciones(alphabet, 15, 5)`. ¡Buena Suerte!

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Justo lo que mandas en el fragmento de código me sirve para continuar mi proyecto, muchas gracias!
Es la primera vez que publico una pregunta, supongo que si lo pones como respuesta le pueda dar como la correcta o por lo menos la que a mi me funcionó.